# memory leak on FeedPaser 5.2.1?

Tags: memory, feedparser

Recently i get to parse a RSS feed using FeedPaser 5.2.1, accidently i find a continuous memory increase as my app. running without break. is there any mistake made by me? Any help would be highly appreciated。

my app. codes as follows(as an example):

```
import feedparser
import time

Url = 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx/feeds/all'
myTag = ""

while(True):
    time.sleep(5)
    feed_data = feedparser.parse(Url,etag=myTag)
    myTag = feed_data.get('etag')
```

code metioned above is compiled into .exe app throngh pyinstaller, and then let it run without break on winserver 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try garbage collecting at the end of while loop before proceeding to loop again. It is most likely that `feed_data` and `myTag` is persisting in in-memory and not getting cleared.

Comment: gc as well as other  techniques don't work. all failed.

Comment: Is CPU memory spiking?

Comment: no，the memory increases step by step as feed_data is not null(etag changed, also new one feed acquired), cpu memory has no fluctuation.